# Shifting binary bits left in Java

Tags: java, binary

I am having a bit of trouble with some shifting of a string in Java.
Essentially I have my Stringbuilder called finalBinary which contains the string of binary bits, "00110101" and I am trying to shift it to the left 5 times, like so;

Input: 00110101

Output: 10100110

I have been reading about bitInversion on the Oracle website and some of the forums on here, but am having no luck :( I really appreciate the help, thankyou so much guys! :)

Comment: Is at an actual `String` object, or are they bits in a number?  Those will be two very different things to manipulate.

Comment: Nothing about this is related to bits.  If you have a `StringBuilder`, then treat it as a normal `String`.

Answer (score 5):

What you are describing is rotating not shifting.  Also you are not rotating bits you are manipulating a `String` of `char`s which happen to represent binary. It could be `"abcdefg"` => `"efgabcd"` as far as the computer is concerned.

```
public static String rotateChars(String str, int count) {
    count % = str.length();
    return str.substring(count) + string.substring(0, count);
}
```